# string as variable name in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL but have worked with several languages in the past.
I don't know the term for what I need to search for it directly, but
"string as variable name mysql" does not provide any answers.

In most languages there is some means of using the content of a variable AS a variable.

--
The specific case I am trying to work with is the following.

Storage table.
ID, L_Count, M_Count, D_Count

---

ID is a 4-digit index where the value is a geographic reference.

L_, M_ and D_Count contain information about how many of each category have been submitted with that location group.

I need to process item serial numbers to find their Geographic reference (distribution site) and based on other data contained in the number, increase, decrease, or even Replace the L_, M_ or D_Count column for the reference found.

IF catfound=L THEN
 the whole thing using L_
and repeating for the other 2 makes 3 times as much code as seems necessary.

IF I could instead make the first step SET CatPrefix=L
And then write the whole thing as (CatPref._Count) it would greatly simplify things.

Comment: Are you looking for MySQL alias identifier? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: If I understand aliases, they allow you to use AS to assign a 'handle' to reference an existing entity.
I updated the question to more accurately reflect what it is I am asking.

Comment: Well, this smells like XY problem. In SQL, you don't use variables nor do you do things like with other (imperative) languages. In SQL, we know stuff in advance, such as what column names are etc. which means you are doing something and your attempted solution is using variables and sticking numbers to them, making them behave as arrays. Now, we could go on all day and try to hack stuff, or easier - explain what it is that you're solving and we could take a stab at that.

Comment: I'll try to add this specific use to the question without making it too long.
I know SQL was not designed as a 'programming' language exactly, but I am hopeful the evolution it has undergone includes a viable solution to this.